# How to sum this vaguely zeta-looking function to QGammafunctions?

Tags: real-analysis, summation, logarithms, zeta-functions, polygamma

For 
$q>1$ 
and 
$s\ge{}1$, 
I'm trying to express

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{(1-q^n)^s}$$

in terms of the [Qpolygamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html).

Just from its definition, it's clear to see that for $s$ the sum is

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{(1-q^n)^1} = \frac{1}{\log (q)} \left( \psi_{ \frac{1}{q} }^{ (0) }(1) + \log ( 1-\tfrac{1}{q} ) \right)$$

and, fixing a $q$ and using Mathematica, for higher $s$, there are also relatively nice expressions involving logs and phi's in that way.

Comment: $(q^n-1)^{-s} = q^{-ns} (1-q^{-n})^{-s} = q^{-ns} \sum_{k =0}^\infty {-s \choose k} (-1)^k q^{-nk}$ so that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{(1-q^n)^s} = \sum_{k =0}^\infty {-s \choose k} (-1)^k \sum_{n=1}^\infty q^{-n(k+s)} = \sum_{k =0}^\infty {-s \choose k}  \frac{(-1)^k}{q^{k+s}-1}$$

Comment: @user1952009: How to read the negative argument binomial factor? There is a Binomial series Wikipedia article, but it didn't give me the tools to interpret it. Did you try your result for some numbers, e.g $q=2, s=3$?

Comment: ${z\choose k} = \frac{\prod_{m=0}^{k-1} (z-m)}{k!}$. The binomial series is  $(1+a)^z = \sum_{k=0}^\infty {z \choose k} a^k $ for any $|a| < 1$ and $z \in \mathbb{C}$